# Pandas Data Frame - logical or of all columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dynamically created data frame which contains, multiple columns with True/False values. Let's say that it looks like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | False |
| False | True | False |
| False | False | False |

I need to create a column which values will be a result of logical or on the rest of the columns.

The output would look like this:

| A | B | C | OR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | False | True |
| False | True | False | True |
| False | False | False | False |

Comment: Dupe not match, OP need create new column, not filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df['OR'] = df.any(axis=1)
```

If need filter only some columns:

```
cols = ['A','B']
df['OR'] = df[cols].any(axis=1)
```